# Не могу повернуть картинку при помощи pygame.transform.rotate()

Tags: python, pygame

Я новичёк ещё в программирование,но можно узнать почему картинка не поворачивается в моём коде,на 90 градусов повернул,потом при нажатие клавиши по идеи должна была картинка повернуться или я не правильно понял как работать с pygame.transform.rotate() и нужно дальше идти штудировать инструкцию по pygame?
Буду благодарен если кто то сможет подсказать)Или я снова где то забыл добавить чёртову запятую или скобки?) Будет чертовски обидно если реально так и произошло..

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption('МАРИО')
W, H = 500, 600
sc = pygame.display.set_mode((W, H), pygame.RESIZABLE)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
FPS = 60

pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load('image/background.png'))
bg_surf = pygame.image.load('image/background.png').convert()
mario_surf = pygame.image.load('image/marioplayer.png').convert()
mario_surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))

mario_up = mario_surf
mario_down = pygame.transform.flip(mario_surf, 0, 1)
mario_left = pygame.transform.rotate(mario_surf, 90)
mario_right = pygame.transform.rotate(mario_surf, -90)
pygame.display.update()

mario_rect = mario_surf.get_rect(center=(240, 408))

mario = mario_up
speed = 1
sc.blit(bg_surf, (0, 0))
sc.blit(mario_surf, mario_rect)



while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        mario = mario_left
        mario_rect.x -= speed
    elif keys[pygame.K_d]:
        mario = mario_right
        mario_rect.x += speed
    elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
        mario = mario_down
        mario_rect.y += speed
    elif keys[pygame.K_w]:
        mario = mario_up
        mario_rect.y -= speed

    sc.blit(bg_surf, (0, 0))
    sc.blit(mario_surf, mario_rect)

    # screen.fill(WHITE)
    # pygame.draw.rect(sc, RED, (x, y, 10, 20))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: да, почти запятая — нужно `sc.blit(mario, mario_rect)` вместо `sc.blit(mario_surf, mario_rect)`, хотя я не понимаю зачем тут вращение, но это уже другое дело)

Comment: не,всёравно не работает,ну что бы когда персонажа двигаешь на лево он двигался на лево и смотрел на лево)) а не смотрел на право)

Comment: https://pastenow.ru/31e169c0f78b8a02b37d45215bc2eae3 я вот такую картинку хочу повернуть на лево когда нажимаю букву A)

Comment: по факту сейчас так https://pastenow.ru/87e541cda62380505b92363e9c7a4bfe - это явно не то что нужно, а то что нужно `pygame.transform.flip` перевертываение а не вращение

Comment: Так отражение выполняется с помощью команды pygame.transform.flip(surface, xbool, ybool),а Поворот - команда pygame.transform.rotate(surface, angle), где surface - поверхность, а angle - угол поворота.

Comment: я о том же и пишу) просто у Вас не правильно применяются команды а так повороты происходят без проблем

Comment: так а разве я на верху эту картинку не отразил? mario_down = pygame.transform.flip(mario_surf, 0, 1)

Comment: поправьте код как я написал в первом коменте и посмотрите сами как работает код, а он работает, просто не так как ожидается

Comment: `mario_left = pygame.transform.flip(mario_surf, 1, 0)` так должно быть для `a`